# How to change dir in sublime text like vim do？

Tags: sublimetext3

I know we can change directory in vim by typing command `:cd /Users/Kron/workspace/project_1`. Is there the same way or some way can do this?

Comment: I don't understand - why would you need to change directory? Sublime is not a text-mode editor like Vim, it uses graphical interfaces to select which files to open, where to save them, etc.

Comment: You're right. Cauze I need to switch between 2 or more projects, I know st has `^+command+p`.So, is there a way? :)

Comment: If you're working on two different projects, just open each in its own window, and switch between the windows as needed, or use `Ctrl-Cmd-P`, like you said. Sublime is a GUI, take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question:

> How to change dir in sublime text like vim do

### Try:

## [**FuzzyFileNav**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFileNav)

> FuzzyFileNav is a simple plugin that allows for quick navigation of
>   the file system from the quick panel. It also allows for deletion,
>   copying, moving, creation of files and folders, and other actions.

---

---

In response to your comment:

> I need to switch between 2 or more projects

### Try:

## [ProjectManager](https://github.com/randy3k/Project-Manager)

It adds the following commands to the Command Palette:

```
Project Manager: Add Project
Project Manager: Import .sublime-project File
Project Manager: Open Project
Project Manager: Open Project in New Window
Project Manager: Append Project
Project Manager: Remove Project
Project Manager: Edit Project
Project Manager: Rename Project
Project Manager: Clear Recent Projects
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience～I already have `FuzzyFileNav` installed. I'll try the second one-`ProjectManager`.